# session set in ashx and get that session on aspx

Tags: asp.net

The following code is working on IE but not on Firefox.
The following code is  setting session on *.ashx file.

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public string PATH = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("..") + @"\UploadFiles\";
    public string prefix = "ANNUAL_";
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {            
        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
        file.SaveAs(PATH + prefix + file.FileName);                
        HttpContext.Current.Session["filename"] = file.FileName;  
        context.Response.Write("1");
    }
}
```

Getting session in *.aspx file is as follows. Even though I can set value into the sessions in *ashx file, the session value is null when session arrives in the *.aspx file.
How can I solve my problem? Could you please give any solution about my problem?

```
using System.Web.SessionState;
public partial class frmImport : System.Web.UI.Page, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string temp = HttpContext.Current.Session["filename"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is probably on the cookie setup on web.config, you need there to be correctly set the path and the domain that set the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in Web.Config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc"  cookieless="true" />
```

The problem has gone !

Comment: I hope you understand the implications, and not only did it because 'it works' :(

Comment: adding this does url tampering with sessionID with the url... which feels not much gud.. Like http://domain/(S(jjbbqk55fc0b3w55fwtyzd55))/Default.aspx to all the pages is there any other method to get session without tampering the url.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the TRUE solution to fix this: [How to access session in aspx that was modified in ashx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465314/how-to-access-session-in-aspx-that-was-modified-in-ashx#comment20148862_14465314)

It's because flash does not send the sessionid to the handler.